# Use C preprocessor to create a statically sized array based on later expansions

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to manually instrument some C or C++.  To do this I would like to declare some structs with statically sized arrays sized to the number of timing statements I manually insert later in the file.  A trivial version for illustration:

```
double array[NUM_TIMESTAMPS];
#define TIMESTAMP() array[__COUNTER__] = get_timestamp();
TIMESTAMP()
TIMESTAMP()
#define NUM_TIMESTAMPS __COUNTER__
```

With cpp -P this expands to:

```
double array[NUM_TIMESTAMPS];
array[0] = get_timestamp();
array[1] = get_timestamp();
```

This will, of course, not pass the compiler because NUM_TIMESTAMPS doesn't get expanded in the c preprocessor's single pass.  Is there a way to either defer the expansion of NUM_TIMESTAMPS to a second parsing, or declare the arrays later in the file?  Code with this sort of instrumentation will not go into production, so dirty hacks are welcome.

Comment: That's not the only way the expanded code will not work, if you do this in the global scope.

Comment: Yeah I know; originally I was trying to keep it a c-preprocessor specific example to get across what I was trying to do.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who posted similar answers involving extern! I tried to accept the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using of `extern` array:

```
extern double array[];    
#define TIMESTAMP() array[__COUNTER__] = get_timestamp();

int main() {
    TIMESTAMP();
    TIMESTAMP();
    return 0;
}

#define NUM_TIMESTAMPS __COUNTER__
double array[NUM_TIMESTAMPS];
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually knew about extern; it just didn't occur to me to use within one file.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you do something like:

```
extern double array [];

#define TIMESTAMP() array[__COUNTER__] = get_timestamp();
TIMESTAMP()
TIMESTAMP()
#define NUM_TIMESTAMPS __COUNTER__
double array[NUM_TIMESTAMPS];
```

In this case, the array is defined with enough information so that the resulting `TIMESTAMP()` expansions can write to it.   The final declaration gives the compiler/linker the size of the array.

It should compile and link properly.   I don't have a compiler with support for `__COUNTER__` available at the moment, so I can't test it.